# AWS EC2: m5.24xlarge vs m5.metal

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Are there any differences between **m5.24xlarge** and **m5.metal**?

According to [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/), both instance types cost the same ($4.608 per Hour) and have the same specifications:

- ECUs (EC2 Compute Unit): 345
- vCPU: 96
- Physical Processor: Intel Xeon Platinum 8175
- Clock Speed: 2.5 GHz
- Memory: 768GiB
- Instance Storage (GB): 4 x 900 (SSD)
- Network Performance: 25 Gigabit
- Cost: $4.608 per Hour

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are the same hardware.

The difference is that `m5.metal` is a **Bare Metal** server that allows you to use a different Hypervisor, such as Hyper-V.

Unless you really know what you are doing, just select a normal `m5.24xlarge` instance.